# LogisticRegression returns same model for different C values

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I have a downsampled dataset with 10000 remaining datapoints, each has 800 features. Still, for whatever C I use, the model predicts the same data. I use the code:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

for C in [1, 40, 1000, 1]:
   logreg = LogisticRegression(C = C, solver='saga').fit(X_train_ds, Y_train_ds)
   Y_pred = logreg.predict(X_test)
```

I tried using both `'saga'` and `'liblinear'` solvers but the model still predicts the same values. I've also tried to put the C value at ridiciously high and low values like 10000000 and 0.00000001 but still nothing changes. 
Does anyone have any Idea where I've gone wrong?

Comment: please post some data and the full code

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code, so I'd guess that there's something strange or particular about your data. If you post a reproducible example it would help.